# Can somebody explain why two users are logged in?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Apparently in my terminal a new "user" appeared. (Sorry for my language but I'm not really familiar with terminals and this stuffs).
What I mean is that in the upper part of my terminal, this sentence appeared

```
Last login: Tue Mar  5 17:58:20 on ttys001
```

And if I type `who` in the terminal:

```
myfullname  console      Jan  1 23:36 
myfullname  ttys000      Mar  5 18:00
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I made a rather heavy edit to focus on the not-yet solved issue.

Comment: Was Jan 1st the last time you rebooted your Mac?

Comment: I don't think I rebooted my Mac but it may be the first time I did something with my terminal. I am afraid, I have no idea what I did (I think that in that period I was learning Git so I installed it and defined something using my terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user with `console` in the second column is your user account logged into your physical Mac with the keyboard and mouse/trackpad. The user with `ttys[nnn]` is you logged in with a terminal application. If there was an IP address after the date column, it would indicate a remote connection.

Try this - start another terminal window and then type the `who` command again, it should now show three users, one console and two ttys.

MacOS is at its heart a time sharing multiuser operating system, a side effect of this is that each terminal window (remote or local) counts as its own login of your user account. These aren't separate instances, as you can create folders in the terminal that will be visible in the Finder and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to start a second terminal session and it shows three users, indeed. BTW I don't understand why the second user (ttys[nnn]) appeared when I installed PostgreSQL. How are those two thing related?

Comment: @andrea They are not related, you would see the same without Postgres installed.

Comment: @nohillside Then why do I have this new user? How can I understand why is there and eventually remove it?

Comment: @Andrea there is no new user. It just shows that the same user (you) is logged in twice, as explained in the answer. The output looks the same for everybody who has one Terminal tab open.

Comment: @nohillside Understood! Thank you for your clarification!